# Copy a list of files with the same names but different extensions to a new directory

Tags: batch-file

With my DSLR camera I have JPGs stored on one SD card and RAW files on the second SD card. Currently I am copying all the .JPG files from one SD card to a folder on the PC, sorting through them, and deleting the unwanted ones.

The second SD card full of RAW files have the same file names as the JPGs but with the extension .NEF.

I want to create a list of the remaining JPG files on the PC, and then only copy the matching .NEF files over to the PC.

I want to create a batch file to automate this.

I can create a simple list of files in a directory by using

```
dir /b /a-d > filelist.txt
```

But this creates a list of filenames including the .JPG extensions, and presumably I need just the filename without the extension, so I can then use the list to copy over the matching .NEF files from the other SD card.

I am trying to use the following to then copy the files, but I can't get it working properly.

```
@echo off
set src_folder=J:\DCIM\101D7100
set dst_folder=D:\Photos\1\RAW
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (filelist.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have a look at what `%%~ni` will give you instead of `%%i`

Comment: I'd use for /f to directly process the dir output `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /A-D X:\path\*.jpg') DO (`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `%%~ni` instead, you use only the name excluding the extension. Assuming you want all the `.NEF` files for the `.JPG` files already in a dir, instead of processing it to a file, then reading from file, simply process it directly. As an example, let's say the directory you used to do `dir /b /a-d > filelist.txt` is `D:\JPEGs`, then simply do:

This simply takes the name of the JPG file and strips the extension, then we copy the name and add .NEF extension.

```
@echo off
set "src_folder=J:\DCIM\101D7100"
set "dst_folder=D:\Photos\1\RAW"
for %%i in ("D:\JPEGS\*.jpg") do (
    xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%~ni.NEF" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

Additionally, always set a variable, using double quotes before variable name and after the path, just to ensure there are no hidden whitespace in your typing.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly. I just needed a little push over the line.

Comment: @Slab Glad I could help.